# Can VS code compile and run a C program in a VirtualBox VM?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, pthreads

The problem :

I have to make program which uses pthreads. To do that , I have an Ubuntu VM on VirtualBox so someone would say im all set. But I was wondering if I can use POSIX libraries while still on my Windows machine.

How I imagine it :
Sort of an extension for vscode such that when I run the code , it runs on a VM and returns me the results of its terminal.

I read a post that talked about how use pthread-win32 , but this is not what im looking for , I want to be able to write POSIX compilable C code

Thanks in advance

Comment: you seem to be asking whether VSCode can compile and run your code in a VM - nothing to do with POSIX

Comment: Maybe [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) is the solution that you are actually looking for.

Comment: A simpler but imperfect solution would be to use cygwin. It's a unix emulation environment. The programs are native Windows binaries, but they are linked to a DLL that makes them act as unix apps. And that includes gcc. It would simply become a question of telling VS Code to use the correct compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). Since you only require the terminal and no visual application, this would suit you perfectly. The link below explains it better then I ever could, but this quote sums it up nicely:

- You can develop in a Linux-based environment, use Linux-specific toolchains and utilities, and run and debug your Linux-based applications all from the comfort of Windows.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

Comment: That sounds like the bones of an answer, @Gerhardh.

Comment: THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I NEEDED . Code runs perfectly thank you

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion for using a Linux style environment on a Windows PC would be to use WSL and connect to WSL from VS Code as [Evert_B already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76015554/6782754).
You can just type `code .` in a WSL shell to start VS Code with the current folder as Workplace. Or you could chose to connect to WSL to setup the connection.

As you already have a VM running Ubuntu on your system, you could use a very similar solution:
VS Code can also [connect to a remote host using SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh).
My knowledge about required VirtualBox network settings to access the VM via TCP/IP is a bit rusty but you should clearly be able to connect to the VM via SSH and then edit, compile and run your code there.